# How to Convert C# datetimeOffset to specified format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

[image]I  need to convert a datetimeoffset  format to below format.

In TimeOffset instead of Dot , I need a colon in before time offset.

```
DateTimeOffset PassDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
  var x = PassDate.ToString("o");
 Console.WriteLine(PassDate.ToString("o"));
```

In the below screenshot after the seconds i got Dot - before offset.Instead of Dot need Colon.

Current O/p:   `2018-03-20T00:00:00.00-05:00`
Expected O/p: `2018-03-20T00:00:00:00-5:00`

Format:

```
2018-03-20T00:00:00.00-05:00  to 2018-03-20T00:00:00:00-5:00
```

Comment: is the `-05` to `-5` also a requirement, or is that a typo?

Comment: @Nyerguds yes utc time to cst time conversion -5:00 .yes need to remove 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTimeOffset PassDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:ffK";
var x = PassDate.ToString(dateFormat);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

`K` and `zzz` modifiers are interchangeable

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTimeOffset PassDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;       
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:ffzzz";
Console.WriteLine(PassDate.ToString(format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   DateTimeOffset PassDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
   var x = PassDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK");
   Console.WriteLine(x);
```

output `2018-03-27T10:46:22+03:00`

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346136(v=vs.110).aspx) to get more information on datetimeformat, it might help.

Comment: There is no link... and link-only answers are generally discouraged.

Comment: I have updated link thanks for pointing @Nyerguds, all the description is already present on the linked page.

Comment: Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/299295) to get more information about link-only answers, it might help.

Comment: @Ahire_Sayali With "generally discouraged" I actually mean, "deleted by moderators".